# How to convert Dates into Specified Format using python?

Tags: python, list, datetime, timezone

I have a list of dates as below:

```
list_dates = ['2013-05-01', '15th Oct 2013', '01-05-13', '2013/FEB/05',. . .]
```

What I want is:

```
list_dates = ['2013-05-01', '2013-10-15', '2013-05-01', '2013-02-05', . . .]
```

Is there ANY way, or package/module to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using the third-party library [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)'s `parser`, which is usually very good at determining the proper way to parse a date (at least way better than I'll ever be :) ). The result of `parser.parse` is a `datetime` object, on which you can call `strftime` with your desired format:

```
In [1]: from dateutil import parser

In [2]: list_dates = ['2013-05-01', '15th Oct 2013', '01-05-13', '2013/FEB/05']

In [3]: [parser.parse(date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date in list_dates]
Out[3]: ['2013-05-01', '2013-10-15', '2013-01-05', '2013-02-05']
```

Comment: when i try this code it throw an error when want to save retuned date in model   {    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer}

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime and time modules for this.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Answer (score 1):

Try datetime.datetime, it provide strptime and strftime method to do this task.